# How to calculate Elasticsearch Field Size

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, memory-management, storage

The question, is there a way to calculate the most expensive field in a Elasticsearch index.

AIM is to calculate and compare the storage and index size of two fields in a elasticsearch Index.

Also is it wise to use dual type fields?

like a string in elasticsearch has `text` field which is searchable and `.keyword` field which is aggregatable

Will it use double the storage and index space?

Answer (score 1):

> is it wise to use dual-type fields. Like a string in elasticsearch has text field which is searchable and .keyword field which is aggregatable

It totally depends on the use case. Maintain both keyword & text representation of a field value if :
a) You need advance searching capability on the field
b) Either your current or future requirements requires capability to either sort or aggregate on the field.

In real life i have seen for short text fields like 'name', 'business-name','tag' etc it makes sense to maintain both. But for larger texts e.g description i don't think there are use cases for aggregation & sorting (in general).

Comment: Make sense but does it require separate memory. in case of 100 bn docs this may be a crucial thing to not have every emall field double typed

Comment: If memory overhead is not there, then es folks would have by default provided with this capability rather than us explicitly defining the same. Please do upvote the answer if it helped